# How energy would be consumed for bending spacetime?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, energy, spacetime, curvature

1. If we could assume that relativity theory is correct about spacetime bending. Can we calculate energy used for moving 1 kg of object in 1 meter by changing the shape of spacetime (simulate gravity)?
2. Which part of it would consume more energy? Size of space was affect, maintain the pinched shape, size and strength of pinching, or timespan?
3. How much energy it would consumed compare to energy used for apply force directly to move it?

Comment: No force is needed just to move an object, in the absence of friction.

Comment: @fs137 if the object is stationary then we do need to apply a force to move it

Comment: @fs137 is correct, you don't need energy to move an object in flat space, if you have an infinite amount of time. Even if you move an object in finite time, all you need is an initial investment in work, all of which you can recover. The net energy of such a movement is zero. The only way you can bend spacetime is by introducing a second massive object, which is no different than applying a conventional force on your object. Your question is therefor trivial and the answer is still none, except for maybe a tiny amount of energy wasted on gravitational waves.

Answer (score 2):

In relativity, gravity is the word we use to describe curved space. Don't think of curved space as simply 'no longer flat', also consider that it includes a gravitational gradient that will cause matter to move across that gradient. As an example, Earth bends the space around where you are right now, with a vertical gravitational gradient, causing you and the things around you to accelerate downward.

When we talk about the consumption of energy, we really mean transfer of energy from one state or form to another (because energy can't be destroyed). With that said, no energy is consumed when you bend spacetime. All matter bends the spacetime around it without cost.

So if you already have enough matter in place to bend spacetime sufficiently to cause your 1kg object to move 1 meter, then the cost is zero. If not, the answer to your question is the amount of energy needed to acquire and move some amount of matter into place near enough to your 1kg object to measure the 1m movement in a given time.

That last part about time is important. If your 1kg object is in a hypothetical space in which it is not affected by the gravity of any other object, you could have a very tiny object a very long way from your mass, and it'll still have enough mass to move your 1kg object. The larger and closer your mass, the faster the 1kg object will accelerate (F = Gm1m2/r2). So in that sense, you could move a 1kg mass with any amount of energy, dictated by how fast you want it to accelerate.

Comment: The point of my question is not using mass of other object to bend space. I mean the another way to use some (negative?) energy and bend spacetime by the equation. I want to know in theory if we could produce it, how the energy would be consumed

Comment: The above is true for both mass and energy, they are interchangeable per E=mc^2. Two points about that; one is you need a lot of energy to equal a little mass as dictated by the equation, and two is that you still need some way to contain the energy in the location you wished to curve spacetime. The most compact method of storing energy is by converting it to matter. But either way, the energy isn't consumed in this case either.

Comment: If curved spacetime doesn't itself contain any energy, how can gravitational waves transmit energy?